# Get average of last 7 days

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm attacking a problem, where I have a value for a a range of dates. I would like to consolidate the rows in my table by averaging them and reassigning the date column to be relative to the last 7 days. My SQL experience is lacking and could use some help. Thanks for giving this a look!!

E.g.
7 rows with dates and values.

```
UniqueId    Date      Value
........    ....     .....
  a       2014-03-20   2
  a       2014-03-21   2
  a       2014-03-22   3
  a       2014-03-23   5
  a       2014-03-24   1
  a       2014-03-25   0
  a       2014-03-26   1
```

Resulting row

```
UniqueId    Date      AvgValue
........    ....      ........
  a       2014-03-26   2
```

First off I am not even sure this is possible. I'm am trying to attack a problem with this data at hand. I thought maybe using a framing window with a partition to roll the dates into one date with the averaged result, but am not exactly sure how to say that in SQL.

Comment: It really annoying that people tag all the available database. Please tag the one which you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am taking following as sample

```
CREATE TABLE some_data1 (unique_id text, date date, value integer);

INSERT INTO some_data1 (unique_id, date, value) VALUES 
 ( 'a', '2014-03-20', 2),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-21', 2),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-22', 3),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-23', 5),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-24', 1),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-25', 0),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-26', 1),
 ( 'b', '2014-03-01', 1),
 ( 'b', '2014-03-02', 1),
 ( 'b', '2014-03-03', 1),
 ( 'b', '2014-03-04', 1),
 ( 'b', '2014-03-05', 1),
 ( 'b', '2014-03-06', 1),
 ( 'b', '2014-03-07', 1)
```

**OPTION A : - Using PostgreSQL Specific Function `WITH`**

```
with cte as (
select unique_id
      ,max(date) date 
from some_data1 
group by unique_id
)
select max(sd.unique_id),max(sd.date),avg(sd.value)
from some_data1 sd inner join cte using(unique_id)
where sd.date <=cte.date 
group by cte.unique_id
limit 7
```

[**> SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/80f51/1/0)

---

**OPTION B : - To work in PostgreSQL and MySQL**

```
select max(sd.unique_id)
      ,max(sd.date)
      ,avg(sd.value) 
from (
      select unique_id
            ,max(date) date 
      from some_data1 
      group by unique_id
     ) cte inner join some_data1 sd using(unique_id)
where sd.date <=cte.date 
group by cte.unique_id
limit 7
```

[**> SQLFDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/80f51d/1/0)

Comment: Thanks everyone!! All the answers were a big help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something along the lines of `SELECT AVG(Value) AS 'AvgValue' FROM tableName WHERE Date BETWEEN dateStart AND dateEnd`  That will get you the average between those dates and you have dateEnd already so you could use that result to create the row you're looking for.

Comment: The query should be a bit smarter than `dateStart` AND `dateEnd`, to take whatever is the `lastDate` and compute last 7 days from `lastDate`

Answer (score 0):

For `SQL Server`, you can follow the below approach. Try this

**1. For weekly value's average**

```
SET DATEFIRST 4
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT *,
    DATEPART(WEEK,[DATE])WK,
    --Find last day in that week 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UNIQUEID,DATEPART(WEEK,[DATE]) ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) RNO,
    -- Find average value of that week
    AVG(VALUE) OVER(PARTITION BY UNIQUEID,DATEPART(WEEK,[DATE])) AVGVALUE
    FROM DATETAB
)
SELECT UNIQUEID,[DATE],AVGVALUE
FROM CTE
WHERE RNO=1
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45b46/2) to view result

**2. For last 7 days value's average**

```
    DECLARE @DATE DATE = '2014-03-26'

    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT UNIQUEID,[DATE],VALUE,@DATE CURRENTDATE 
        FROM DATETAB
        WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-7,@DATE) AND @DATE
    )
    SELECT UNIQUEID,CURRENTDATE [DATE],AVG(VALUE) AVGVALUE
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY UNIQUEID,CURRENTDATE
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/45b46/3) to view result

Comment: Are u using Sql Server as database? @user1026498

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL a window function might be what you want:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS some_data;

CREATE TABLE some_data (unique_id text, date date, value integer);

INSERT INTO some_data (unique_id, date, value) VALUES 
 ( 'a', '2014-03-20', 2),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-21', 2),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-22', 3),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-23', 5),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-24', 1),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-25', 0),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-26', 1),
 ( 'a', '2014-03-27', 3);

WITH avgs AS (
    SELECT unique_id, date, 
        avg(value) OVER w AS week_avg,
        count(value) OVER w AS num_days
    FROM some_data
    WINDOW w AS (
        PARTITION BY unique_id 
        ORDER BY date 
        ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))
SELECT unique_id, date, week_avg
FROM avgs
WHERE num_days=7
```

Result:

```
 unique_id |    date    |      week_avg      
-----------+------------+--------------------
 a         | 2014-03-26 | 2.0000000000000000
 a         | 2014-03-27 | 2.1428571428571429
```

Questions include:

1. What happens if a day from the preceding six days is missing? Do we want to add it and count it as zero?
2. What happens if you add a day? Is the result of the code above what you want (a rolling 7-day average)?