# rolling sum over the last 7 days, how to include missing dates - postresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get something like this but I have only the first two columns:

```
dates          sales     rolling_sum7days           
01-01-2019     1         1
02-01-2019     3         4
03-01-2019     5         9
04-01-2019     2        11
05-01-2019     7        18
06-01-2019     8        26
08-01-2019    10        35
09-01-2019     1        32
10-01-2019     8        39
```

I have come up with this but have not find a way to deal with missing values such as the sales for 07-01-2019

```
SELECT dates 
sum(sales) over(order by dates ROWS BETWEEN 6 preceding AND CURRENT ROW) 
from table
```

What should I correct?
found some similar problems but they did not solved this issue.
for example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101838/get-average-of-last-7-days)

Comment: Please explain how you get 35 for 08-01-2019 and 32 for 09-01-2019 and 39 for 10-01-2019?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5ad607347f3240c1f7cfe13103c9b5e8)

```
SELECT
    gs::date as dates,
    COALESCE(mt.sales, 0) AS sales,
    sum(sales) over(order by gs ROWS BETWEEN 6 preceding AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM
    mytable mt
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    generate_series('2019-01-01', '2019-01-11', interval '1 day') gs
    ON gs = mt.dates
```

To fill missing dates within a certain range you can use `generate_series()` for this date range and do an outer join.

If you do not want to fix the gs parameters then, of course, you could calculate them before, e.g. taking the MIN and MAX from your table:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3fffeb979d66f532af9949500ec99c80)

```
WITH date_bounds AS (
    SELECT min(dates), max(dates) FROM mytable
)
SELECT
    gs::date as dates,
    COALESCE(mt.sales, 0) AS sales,
    sum(sales) over(order by gs ROWS BETWEEN 6 preceding AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM
    mytable mt
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
    generate_series(
         (SELECT min FROM date_bounds), 
         (SELECT max FROM date_bounds), 
         interval '1 day'
    ) gs
    ON gs = mt.dates
```

Answer (score 4):

Postgres supports window ranges with intervals.  So you can do what you want very simply:

```
SELECT t.*,
       SUM(t.sales) OVER (ORDER BY t.dates
                          RANGE BETWEEN interval '6 day' preceding AND current row
                         ) as rolling_sum7days
FROM t;
```

There is no need to expand the data to every day.  That just slows down the query.